# Files disappeared after Mavericks upgrade

Tags: macos

I upgrade my iMac to Mavericks last night and now I can't see any of my files.  None of the applications I use showed up (i.e. Photoshop and Lightroom), my desktop doesn't have any of my files, none of my iMovie projects show up.  If I do a search for them I can see them but I don't know where they are located. It says Desktop but my Desktop is blank. Its like I'm starting with a brand new computer and have to set everything up again.

Comment: There was a bug in a recent Mavericks update causing the Users folder to disappear.<br>
You can read about it in this article:http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/05/16/os-x-1093-bug-hides-users-folder-easy-fix-available-via-terminal meanwhile you can try updating again since a new update should have fixed it.

Comment: The bug was actually iTunes, but the rest of your comment is correct - perform a full update and ensure iTunes is included, then let us know if it fixes it.  if it does, @dennismuys can add it as an answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in a recent iTunes update causing the Users folder to disappear.
 You can read about it in [this article](http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/05/16/os-x-1093-bug-hides-users-folder-easy-fix-available-via-terminal) meanwhile you can try updating again since a new update should have fixed it.
Just make sure to update iTunes, you can do this by going to the updates tab in the App Store, or by going to iTunes and in the menu clicking iTunes/ find new versions.